# Is there a way to run a function when my Discord bot joins a server? - Discord.py Rewrite

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm creating a Discord bot using the discord.py rewrite.

When I invite it to a server, I want it to add all of the users in the server to a dictionary which will store their stats, etc.

I've looked around and can't seem to find a solution to this problem.

I want something like this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_bot_invite(guild):
    ...
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "discord.py rewrite" anymore. The rewrite branch of discord.py is simply v1 now.
See https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html.

The event you're looking for is probably [`on_guild_join`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_guild_join).
Then, you can use the [`members` attribute](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.members) of the [`Guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#guild) object that's passed to that event handler.